# How to remove everything but tables from html code

Tags: html, notepad++

How can I delete from `html` code everything but tables? I can target tables like this:

`<table.+?<\/table>`

But how can I inverse my selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery remove function, and its 'not' selector. Something looks like;

$( "body:not(table)").remove();

https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

OR,

Simply read html file as string and delete everything that does not match table tag using string manuplation. When table is found do nothing but iterate until you find Closing tag of that table

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't need notepad++. open html page in browser, 
in console, if in jquery

```
$('table').html()
```

or in js

```
var tabletext = ''
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('table')
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    tabletext +=  elements[i].innerHTML
}
```

copy paste to a new file

Comment: Thanks for answer. But is there any way to to it in Notepad++? I need to make some other changes in code as well.